# Kubuntu 16.04 on Dell XPS 9550 trackpad woes part 2: my hand keeps hitting the trackpad and moving the cursor

Tags: kubuntu, dell, touchpad

Believe it or not, this is the first time I'm using a laptop with a trackpad (until now, all my laptops have been Thinkpads, and I've always disabled the trackpad on those. However, my T61p was showing its age, so I got me a Dell XPS 9550).

The problem: the roots of my palms (the thenors) keep touching the trackpad and moving the cursor. I *could* potentially change my typing habits and not rest my hands on the laptop, but is there a software way of disabling the upper corners of the trackpad?

Comment: Try `sudo synclient TouchpadOFF=1`

Comment: @AlcuinArundel Wouldn't that completely disable the entire touchpad until it's manually re-enabled? It seems JayEye wants to only disable the upper corners (or possibly disable the trackpad only while typing)

Comment: Yes, I missed the "upper corners" part.

Comment: Here's a solution you could try: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/30rdwb/running_plasma_5_is_there_any_to_turn_off_tap_to/cpv3s0a

Comment: I don't want to disable tap-to-click.